Why UBI in u-boot read 12 bytes from FLASH?
I am working on an embedded Linux system (5.10.24), where the u-boot-2013-10 is used as the bootloader.
The Uboot and kernel are both enabled MTD/UBI/UBIFS on the NAND FLASH.
Now I hit an issue in u-boot, where the UBI in it is reading 11 and 12 bytes from MTD device.
UBI DBG: ubi_leb_read: read 4096 bytes from LEB 0:0:0
UBI DBG: ubi_io_read: read 4096 bytes from PEB 142:4096
UBI DBG: ubi_leb_read: read 126976 bytes from LEB 0:1:0
UBI DBG: ubi_io_read: read 126976 bytes from PEB 147:4096
UBI DBG: ubi_leb_read: read 126976 bytes from LEB 0:2:0
UBI DBG: ubi_io_read: read 126976 bytes from PEB 148:4096
UBIFS: recovery needed
UBI DBG: ubi_leb_read: read 11 bytes from LEB 0:8:118784
UBI DBG: ubi_io_read: read 11 bytes from PEB 361:122880
UBI DBG: ubi_leb_read: read 12 bytes from LEB 0:8:120830
UBI DBG: ubi_io_read: read 12 bytes from PEB 361:124926

I am NOT familar with UBI or UBIFS, so I am puzzled by the last 4 reads, is it reasonable for UBI to read 11 or 12 bytes from lower MTD device? If so, in which case does it read these count of data? (My UBIFS may have dirty or in-air changes/corruption).
